# Strange latex error involving bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I'm baffled by the recent manner in which my LaTeX has been acting up. I'm using TeXmaker on a Mac. My document was compiling fine, but I had put in some new references, so to get them to show up I compiled my .bib file. There were no errors. After recompiling (I hadn't changed anything since the last time that compile worked; all I did was compile the BibTeX file), I got the following error:

```
Unicode char \u8:ﬁ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and can no longer compile. However, after clearing out all the `.aux`, etc. files, I can compile just fine...but still without references (and if I compile the `.bib`, I get the same bug again)

Can anybody suggest a fix?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) We typically do not add thanks to posts. You can easily extend thanks by upvoting replies.

Comment: Please, paste here the content of you `.bib` file. Use the code block to this. Probably there are some characters not allowed on some entry of the `bib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bibtex file contains a `ﬁ` character, that is, a ligature of `f` and `i`. Replace all occurences of this character with the two ordinary characters `fi`.

Comment: How did you do the first `fi` on your code? It looks different from the last code `fi`.

Comment: @Sigur Of course it look different, the latter shall replace the first. The first one is a unicode character for the f-i-ligature, and latex complains about it when processing the `bbl` file. I copied it directly from the error message the OP posted.

Comment: Ah, I see. His post has the ligature. Thanks.